# Acumatica: Custom Processing Screen - <SELECT> is left on screen after processing

Tags: processing, screen, customization, acumatica

I created a custom processing screen to transmit records to a web service but it returns a good record when it isn't.  The web service always returns good record.
To know if it is good or bad you have to loop through the response.  Is there a way to stop that?  I think I need to add a delegate, but everything I do fails.  I keep being left with

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The moment the good record comes back is when the Sendasync comes back.  I've tried to mess around with a delegate but I can't get it to work.  I think I need to create a delegate to do the error checking but either that is wrong or I use the wrong syntax.

```
 public async Task<T> PostStreamAsync<T>(string requestUrl, CancellationToken cancellationToken, object content)
    {
        addHeaders();

        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl))
        using (var httpContent = CreateHttpContentForStream(content))
        {
            request.Content = httpContent;

            using (var response = await _httpClient
                .SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken)
                .ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
               // response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
            }
        }
    }


public class TransmitPurchaseOrder : PXGraph<TransmitPurchaseOrder>
{

    public PXCancel<POOrder> Cancel;

    public PXProcessing<POOrder, Where<POOrderExt.usrProcessed, Equal<False>>> UnprocessedRecords;

    public TransmitPurchaseOrder()
    {
        UnprocessedRecords.SetProcessDelegate(ProcessPOLinesAsync);
        UnprocessedRecords.SetSelected<POOrder.selected>();
    }
```

Comment: Please also add the view definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial problem I had was that  was in the line of the screen.  That was because I had a form and filter that I added knowing it was going to come into play someday.  Once both were removed,  goes away.